# OpenCV recognizes my camera but cant read

Tags: c++, opencv, camera

I've been working on a computer vision project for a while now using the webcam of my laptop (it shows up as "HD WebCam" with 640x480 res) but want to use this program with the camera of my DJI-Inspire1 drone. The camera is recognized and opened but it fails to read images from it.

In more detail:

in my player class load camera function:

```
 capture.open(-1);     // this opens a window with a combobox showing all 
 //the cameras i have. Selecting the DJI camera fails 
 //the read while selecting the webcam fails and crashes.
 // capture.open(0); opens the webcam succesfully
 // capture.open(1);
```

open(1) seems to try to open DJI-Camera but gives different values than 
open(-1) and crashes after reading a frame (the frames are entirely 
black 720x480 CV_8UC3) In debug mode it crashes whie reading the frame with a Segmentation fault and points to a dissassembly of "DriverProc" (i guess?) and a line with a movdqa command.

```
 // capture.open(2); oddly also seems to try and open DJI-camera now with 
 // 720x486 resolution resulting in a black 720x486 CV_8UC3 image (no crashes).   
 // anything above open(2) fails and crashes 
 if(capture.isOpened()){
     // in here i check the values of different properties, they are:
     //                               open(-1)     open(1)      open(2)     HD WEBCAM  
     //    CV_CAP_PROP_FORMAT =       0            -1           -1          -1
     //    CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH =  720          720          720         640
     //    CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT = 486          480          486         480
     //    CV_CAP_PROP_FOURCC =       1.49883e+09  -4.66163e+08 -4.66163e08 8.44715e+08
     //    CV_CAP_PROP_FPS =          30           0            0           0
 }
```

next up is in the main loop of the player class (its on its own thread)

```
while(!stop){
     // this is the command that tries to read the next frame
     if(!capture.read(frame)){
          // this happens for the open(-1) version
     }
}
```

So basically the resolution is either 720x486 or 720x480 which is very strange, there seems to be three cameras connected yet the list with capture.open(-1) shows only 2. open(2) will succefully load a black image :P. Im certain that the camera is working since i can view it in other applications such as "Livestream Studio". The Video goes from the camera to a controller (which reduces the resolution to 720 i think) wirelessly and from there to a [Blackmagic design](https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/products/intensity) HDMI->USB3.0 converter and from there to the PC. After Intense googling i found out that the fourcc code 1.49883e+09 for the open(-1) version is indeed "2VUY" which is used by Blackmagic so that makes sense. could find what the -4.66163e08 ones mean though.

I'm using openCV 3.0.0 , minGW4.92 32bit , Qt 5.5.0

So does anyone have any ideas as to what the problem might be? I'm all out of ideas.

Comment: What resolution SHOULD the camera be transmitting? You say you think the resolution is reduced? (Id start by finding out what the video's resolution is.) Finally what format are you transmitting the video in?

Comment: @Rootix I have no controll over the transmitted video but there is a setting that says NTSC so maybe that, when opened in a cam viewer app "dvdrive" it says 720x486 so i guess thats it but the app also just displays a black screen.

Comment: Is the camera functioning properly outside of opencv? Also, I see your using mingw, have you tried the same code except on gcc + linux? I have found opencv and video cameras can be finicky on windows.

Comment: @Rootix yes, it works perfectly in "livestream studio" but not in "dvdriver". I'm afraid I've never tried linux :(

Comment: @Rootix my suspicion is it has sometging to do with the blackmagic hdmi to usb3 converter...

Comment: If your able to pull it up outside of opencv, then I would guess it is capable of functioning correctly. I would research the camera model and see if there are any known conflicts with it, and work-arounds. (I am understanding correctly that the code functions if you use the webcam)

Comment: @Rootix yes the webcam works perfectly. Yeah thats what I'm doing :( i'll post here if i find an answer

Comment: does it work with ditectShow (graphstudioNext) and does it work with VLC?

Comment: @Micka, i can't get VLC to open either it nor the webcam for some reason, will try to figure that out

Comment: It seems that one might need to use "Decklink SDK" by blackmagic... to bad there isn't any clear guide to installing it (the windows version comes with .idl files instead of the usual dlls and .h)

Comment: Maxx, from my experience with OpenCV and USB cameras: try skipping some of the first frames when capturing starts (they might be not OK) and always check if frame.data is not 0 when you have frames.

Comment: Ok thanks for the tip, i will try it out on monday